# Getting error as " java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index" while executing SQL query through java

Tags: java, jdbc

Can anyone suggest what i am doing wrong here, trying to print the SQL query output in console, but getting error as " java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index".

```
import java.io.*;  
import java.sql.*;  

public class RetrieveFile {  
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@123.43.23.43:8080/orcl", "Test", "*****");

            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from MSG where MSD='1234'");
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            // rs.next();//now on 1st row
            while (rs.next()) {

                int numberOfColumns = 0;
                for (int column = 1; column >= numberOfColumns; column++) {

                    if (column > 1)
                        System.out.print(", ");
                    System.out.print(rs.getString(column));
                }
            }

            con.close();

            // System.out.println("success" + (rs.getString(1)));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting some part of response, but end getting the following error.

> ERROR:
>
> null, 1234, 389, OUR, NOW, USD, 0, 0, FR1, wert, USD, 0, null, 0, 0, null, DR, null, null, 0, 0, null, null, null, null, null, null,
>   null, null, null, 0, 2, 2019-06-11 00:00:00.0, null, null, null, null,
>   null, null, null, java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index
>         at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
>         at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:146)
>         at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:208)
>         at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.getString(OracleResultSetImpl.java:379)
>         at RetrieveFile.main(RetrieveFile.java:20)
>       Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Duser.home=C:\Users\45060849

Please include the table structure of MSG in output
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why `numberOfColumns = 0`?

Comment: Can you show us the table structure of `MSG`?

Comment: Why `for (int column = 1; column >= numberOfColumns; column++)`? Your code doesn't make any sense whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you neither know the number of columns, nor their data types, you have to check them via `ResultSetMetaData`.
The following example does it in a separate method, which does not yet consider every possible SQL data type, but some very common ones.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@123.43.23.43:8080/orcl", "Test", "*****");

        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from MSG where MSD='1234'");
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

        try {
            printResultColumns(rs);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        con.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

You basically request the amount of columns, use it as iteration border and then you can check the type of column `i`. That is required due to different methods for different data types.

```
public static void printResultColumns(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException {
    ResultSetMetaData rsmd = resultSet.getMetaData();
    int columnCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();

    while (resultSet.next()) {
        // you get a single result row in here, not the entire ResultSet
        for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++) {
            switch (rsmd.getColumnType(i)) {
            case Types.VARCHAR:
            case Types.LONGVARCHAR:
            case Types.CHAR:
                System.out.println(resultSet.getString(i));
                break;
            case Types.DOUBLE:
                System.out.println(resultSet.getDouble(i));
                break;
            case Types.INTEGER:
                System.out.println(resultSet.getInt(i));
                break;
            case Types.DATE:
                System.out.println(resultSet.getDate(i).toString());
                break;
            case Types.TIMESTAMP:
                System.out.println(resultSet.getTimestamp(i).toString());
                break;
            case Types.BOOLEAN:
                System.out.println(resultSet.getBoolean(i));
                break;
            case Types.DECIMAL:
            case Types.NUMERIC:
                System.out.println(resultSet.getBigDecimal(i));
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("This column type (" 
                        + rsmd.getColumnTypeName(i)
                        + ") is currently not supported in method \"printResultColumns\""
                        + ".\nAdd it as case there.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response, now i am getting java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name.

Comment: @Routray Have you adjusted the query `String` to include `"... MSG AS message ..."`?

Comment: sorry it was miss from my side, now i have updated, but getting error as "ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended"

Comment: @Routray my solution is wrong, I will soon provide a better one.

Comment: @Routray Have you tried my answer? Does it work? Are there any problems?

Comment: thanks for the update, please don't mind can you please merge my code and your code....i am bit confusion as u r using the SQLException, it means i don't need to use try, catch block. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please ignore my previous question

Comment: now i am getting error as This column type (1) is currently not supported in method "printResultColumns".
Add it as case there.

Comment: although i am getting response but still its printing with value as "This column type (1) is currently not supported in method "printResultColumns".
Add it as case there."

Comment: @Routray good. I have written `getColumnType(i)` in the `default` case, but it should have been `getColumnTypeName(i)`. Sorry for that...

Comment: i am sorry for the confusion, but its not retrieving data properly Actual Data Retrieved:-2
1961107205906E01
1961111003602U0C
1
2019-06-11
1
null
null
null
1
1
2 Expected:-241389329
1961107205906E01
1961111003602U0C
GCOV_CONF
11-JUN-19
12:00:36
null
GMT
null
0

Comment: @Routray Please edit your question to include the table structure of `MSG`. Then we can find out why the output is not the desired one.

Comment: please find the below datatype of column--- java.math.BigDecimal
java.lang.String
java.lang.String
null
null
null
java.lang.String
java.lang.String
java.math.BigDecimal

Comment: @Routray I have added the corresponding types for `BigDecimal` in the `switch` statement in the code of my answer. Are the `null` values results of the method `getColumnTypeName()`? If yes, what database are you using? SQL server, MySQL, Sybase, H2 or anything like that?

Comment: i am using Oracle11g. after updating code i am getting response as in true and false

Comment: @Routray Again, my fault... I have updated the code. There was `getBoolean` for the cases `DECIMAL` and `NUMERIC`, which was just wrong. Now it is `getBigDecimal`;

Comment: thanks for the update, it works fine in all case but where there are CHAR, its returning is as CHAR instead of value. Any clue how to handle java.lang.String. because where ever datatype as java.lang.String its printing as CHAR.

Comment: @Routray then check my most recent update, which handles `CHAR` and `LONGVARCHAR` the same as `VARCHAR`. I hope that will fix it.

Comment: @ deHaar, thanks a lot. Now its working perfectly. Now i have to store this value in text file.

Comment: @Routray very good... I hope this helped you understanding how database access works in Java via JDBC. For future projects, consider using a framework like [MyBatis](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/);

Comment: its really helpful to understand a beginner like me.

Answer (score 1):

The `java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index` means that a column with the index you are trying to access doesn't exist.

The variable `numberOfColumns` is always smaller than the `column` variable, so you are trying to get values from columns with indexes larger than the column count.

Answer (score 0):

```
int numberOfColumns = 0;
for (int column = 1; column >= numberOfColumns; column++) {
```

`column> = numberOfColumns` condition will call infinitely `getString (column)`.
Modify the for statement.

try this

```
numberOfColumns = 0;
while(rs.next()) {
  numberOfColumns++;
  String s = rs.getString(numberOfColumns);
  //...
}
```

Comment: thanks for the update, i have tried the above query but still facing the same issue:                                                                             int numberOfColumns = 0;
while(rs.next()) {
  numberOfColumns++;
  String s = rs.getString(numberOfColumns);
  
 for (int column = 1; column >= numberOfColumns; column++) {

        if(column > 1) System.out.print(", ");
        System.out.print(rs.getString(column));

Comment: `rs.next()` returns true for a new **row**, each row can have 1 or more columns. Your solution counts the number of rows, and return the column corresponding to the row number. When there are more rows than columns, this will still throw an exception (and it is unlikely this is what the OP wants or needs).